# Element to be visible only for particular height

Tags: html, css, visibility

I am new to HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I have an element (navigation dots) that should be visible only for a particular segment of my page. The rest of the time I would prefer it to be hidden. I tried using media query:

```
@media screen and (min-height:200vh) and (max-height: 600vh)
{
.invisible{
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

The segment is in one div. So would it be possible to make this div visible while hovering on the other div?

Comment: Please include the HTML and javscript too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all using `vh` and `vw` in your media queries is not going to work. By definition `100vh` is 100% of the viewport height of a device viewing your site. What this means is a `min-height: 200vh` media query will only apply to devices whose viewport is **2x higher than the device viewport itself**. Nothing can be two times higher than itself, unless it's 0, so this media query will never take effect.

That said, I hope you can clarify what exactly you mean by **segment** and what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to...

1. Hide the *nav-dots* when a client's viewport **height** doesn't meet a certain value?
2. Hide *nav-dots* on a particular DOM **element** such as `<p>` or `<div>`?
3. Hide *nav-dots* when a user has **scrolled** past a certain threshold?

To answer the second scenario and your later question about hiding a div while hovering on another I propose the following solution. However I'd be happy to update my answer if this is not what you were getting at.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="my_segment">
  <div class="nav-dots">
    Navigation dots go here
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we have assigned the `my_segment` id to the element we want to hide the *nav-dots* on. Note that you can use a unique **id** only once per page.

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFCCAA;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Find our element
let seg = document.getElementById('my_segment');

// Add a mouseover event handler to our element
seg.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  // Find nav-dots inside our element
  let nav_dot_elements = seg.getElementsByClassName('nav-dots');
  // Remove the 'invisible' class
  nav_dot_elements[0].classList.remove('invisible');
});

// Add a mouseout event handler
seg.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  // Find nav-dots inside our element
  let nav_dot_elements = seg.getElementsByClassName('nav-dots');
  // Add the 'invisible' class
  nav_dot_elements[0].classList.add('invisible');
});
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGwbeY)

Since you are new to JS I tried to keep this example simple. This only works if you use the 'hover to display' behaviour on one element **and** you only use one 'nav-dots' element inside this container. Try it out for yourself and let me know how it works!

Comment: Misacorp, this didn't work for me. By segment i meant another div. Basically i wanted my navdots to display only in that div. I wrote a jquery code which isn't perfect but works a little.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container1").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $(".fourth").offset().top;
    var bottomOfOthDiv = $("#fifth").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv && $(window).scrollTop() < bottomOfOthDiv ) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $(".container1").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else
        $(".container1").hide();
        
    });
});

Comment: Judging by your code you want `.container1` to show when the user has scrolled into `.fourth` and hide `.container1` in any other case. Your code looks fine, though you will run into issues if you have multiple instances of `.fourth` or `.container1` on your page. If you'd like a solution to this or other refinements, could you provide the rest of your code, for example as a working Codepen demo.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Right now, I'm trying to learn these languages by seeing if I can build other websites on my own. (This is the original website : https://gettothegame.com.au/)

https://codepen.io/nightshade235/pen/KXqmJg

I have yet to make the code responsive, so please open it in full screen if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your code and reference site. I believe I understood what you want to achieve. Have a look at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/LzLqNj). If it works like you want it to, try to do the following things: 1) Successfully add a new section and its respective progress tracker icon. 2) Read through the JavaScript code. It is commented to explain what is happening. 3) Identify which parts of your site are which on the Codepen. Only after these should you try  implementing it on your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot Misacorp. I'll study it thoroughly before implementing.